# How to do page transitions with svelte/sapper

Tags: sapper, svelte-transition

I want to realize a simple page (route) transition in Sapper. Something that is easily achievable with Nuxt for example. Does anyone have an idea how to realize that with Sapper?

I already wrapped my page content into a div with a transition:fade directive. This works. Yet, the two pages transition at the same time, meaning while one page transitions out the other one already transitions in. It would be great if someone pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me just start of by saying I don't know if this is the most effective way to do it. This is the way I solved it and it works great for me.

I first made my own custom variation of the 'fade' transition and put it in 'components/pageFade.js'

```
import { sineOut } from "svelte/easing";

let duration = 250;
let delay = duration;

let delayZero = 0;

export const fadeIn = _ => ({
  duration,
  delay,
  easing: sineOut,
  css: t => `opacity: ${t}`
});
export const fadeOut = _ => ({
  duration,
  delay: delayZero,
  easing: sineOut,
  css: t => `opacity: ${t}`
});
```

1. The delayZero variable is there because for some reason it won't take '0' directly and will break.
2. The duration variable is the length of the fade in milliseconds

Then for all files I wanted to have this transition on I did the following:

```
<script>
  import { fadeIn, fadeOut } from "../components/pageFade";

  // All your other JS goes here
</script>

<style>
  /* Styles go here */
</style>

<main in:fadeIn out:fadeOut>
  <!-- All the normal HTML goes here -->
</main>
```

I would then use that as a template on almost every single one of the pages, which seems like a lot but it's not too bad.

Hope it helps and let me know if you have any other questions!

Max

Comment: If I want the same transition for all pages, do I need to add an individual transition to each page component or is there a way to add it in one place and have it executed for pages components?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to include **transition in _layout.svelte** and don't need to include them in every route here is an alternative.

Here is a simple **fly in/out from top transition**.

```html
<!-- src/component/PageTransitions.svelte -->
<script>
  import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';
  export let refresh = '';
</script>

{#key refresh}
  <div
    in:fly="{{ y: -50, duration: 250, delay: 300 }}"
    out:fly="{{ y: -50, duration: 250 }}" 
    >
    <slot/>
  </div>
{/key}
```

And here is the Sapper **layout** component

```html
<!-- src/routes/_layout.svelte for Sapper -->

<script>
  import { page } from '$app/stores'; // svelte@next
  import Nav from '../components/Nav';
  import PageTransitions from '../components/PageTransitions';
  export let segment;
</script>

<Nav {segment}/>

<PageTransitions refresh={segment}>
  <slot/>
</PageTransitions>
```

And here is the SvelteKit (svelte@next) **layout** component

```html
<!-- src/routes/$layout.svelte for Svelte@next -->

<script>
  import { page } from '$app/stores'; // svelte@next
  import Nav from '../components/Nav';
  import PageTransitions from '../components/PageTransitions';
</script>

<Nav segment={$page.path}/>

<PageTransitions refresh={$page.path}>
  <slot/>
</PageTransitions>
```

And for completeness here is a simple **Nav** component

```html
<!-- src/component/Nav.svelte -->
<script>
    export let segment;
</script>

<style>
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .current {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <a href="/" class='{segment === undefined ? "current" : ""}'>Home</a>
  <a href="/about" class='{segment === "about" ? "current" : ""}'>About</a>
</div>
```

**NOTES:**
We make the component reactive by creating a `refresh` prop and using `key` directive which means that when the key changes, svelte removes the component and adds a new one, therefore triggering the transition.

In the layout component we pass the segment (route) as `refresh` prop and therefore the refresh key changes as the route changes.

[Here is a demo](https://amazing-kirch-8cb3f5.netlify.app/) of the sample code above and the [github repo](https://github.com/GiorgosK/svelte-page-transitions)

Comment: It's important to warn to change for the navigation elements the CSS z-index as well as the CSS position to relative in order to not fight with the animation.

Comment: Additionally, for Sapper your code is wrong/outdated. Instead of using "import { page } from '$app/stores';", you need to import page store this way:
https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Stores

Answer (score 3):

FYI [@max-larsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10569063/max-larsson), from your code, `fadeIn` is defined as a function which needs no arguments and returns an object having a `duration` property equal to the value of the `duration` variable at this scope. same with `delay`. Note `easing` is defined as the name, with the value of `sineOut`.

This may be your issue if you just tried to put a literal `0` where `delay` was. I see you tried making `delayZero`, but used it likely in a different way than you intended. You probably meant to write this:

```js
export const fadeOut = _ => ({
  duration,
  delay: 0,
  easing: sineOut,
  css: t => `opacity: ${t}`
});
```

When I tried this, it works just fine for me. Thanks for sharing your example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Svelte Kit has changed since @GiorgosK answer, because I cannot make it work with the code in his answer.
But fortunately, his [github repo](https://github.com/GiorgosK/svelte-page-transitions) has been update with the solution, thanks !
The `page.path` properties much be used in [module context](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/sharing-code)

This is my version without a specific component for page transition :

```html
    <!-- src/route/__layout.svelte -->
    <script context="module">
        export const load = async ({ page }) => ({
            props: {
                key: page.path,
            },
        });
    </script>
    
    <script>
        import { fly } from "svelte/transition";
        export let key;
    </script>
    
    <nav>
        <a href="/foo">foo</a>
        <a href="/bar">bar</a>
    </nav>
    
    {#key key}
        <div
            in:fly={{ x: 50, duration: 2500 }}
            out:fly={{ y: -50, duration: 2500 }}
        >
            <slot />
        </div>
    {/key}
```

Maybe @GiorgosK can share some insight about that change.